# Using SVG in MS Word gives it black background

Tags: microsoft-word, svg, vector-graphics

I have a following SVG which renders properly in browser:

[image]

You can download it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A-J8bChYWS6sOdNdit7UiBtOqhm4M78Q/view?usp=sharing)

When I try to copy paste it in the MS Word, it renders with black background:

[image]

How can I use it in Word doc, without rasterizing it, that is keeping its vector format intact, since I dont want it to pixelate once I convert the doc to pdf?

PS: Preferably with some simpler way without requiring any heavy image editing software installation. But if you have any solution which involving special software please do share.